# What CSS properties govern how a webpage reacts to window resizing?

Tags: html, css, resize

I just wonder because I know that my page goes haywire if you try to make it too small. Facebook, StackOverflow and almost any other well programmed site calmly adjusts the page format until they run out of 'breathing room' at which point the page is just 'eaten' by the browser's borders. How do these well programmed sites format themselves so nicely as to cope with window resizing? Are there CSS properties specifically made to help with this?

Comment: SO uses `width: XXXpx; margin: 0 auto;`.

Comment: set a min-width on the outermost container.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should look into "Fluid" CSS designs.  These are CSS rules that are designed to manage a pages width.

A common way of doing this is to use `max-width` and `min-width` to manage the over all width of the website.

For example:

[Click here to see a live example.](http://pastehtml.com/view/b28j4kui0.html)

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>Width Test</title>
    <style>
        #main-content {
            background-color: #EEF;
            border: 1px solid #003;
            max-width: 45em;
            min-width: 20em;
            padding: 1em;
            margin: 0 auto; /* center */
        }
        .box {
            border: 1px solid #000;
            background: #363;
            color: #fff;
            padding: .25em;
        }
        .left {
            float: left;
            margin: .5em 1em .5em 0;
        }
        .right {
            float: right;
            margin: .5em 0 .5em 1em;
        }
    </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="main-content">
            <p>Resize Me...</p>
            <span class="box left">left</span>
            <span class="box right">right</span>
            <p>Fluid Layout</p>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

The key element here is the styling on `#main-content`.  The rest of that is so you can see it in action.

Answer (score 2):

You can center your site by using a main "wrapper" `div`.

```
<div id="wrapper">
    //all you content here
</div>
```

Then in you css your set the "wrapper" as follows

```
#wrapper{
    width:900px //or whatever
    margin: 0 auto; }
```

This gives it a width and a flexible margin.  When the window is resized too small, it just "eats" it, as you say.

The key here is a flexible layout, either make the margin flexible (as I outlined above) or make the content flexible.

Another way to do this is to make almost everything flexible, something like this..

```
#wrapper{
    border:1px solid red;
    width:50%;
    min-width:300px;
    margin:0 25%;
    height:50px; //for display only
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/jasongennaro/6FCjZ/1/

Comment: why do u keep the height fixed? when the person zooms in oe zooms out the vertical size of content also increases/decreases

Comment: Thanks @lovesh. That height was just for display, to show the `div` as a square, otherwise it would be flat, as `div`s without content are 0 height.  Edited to be clearer.

Answer (score 1):

Both those websites are a fixed width but with expanding header backgrounds. There's nothing special going on.

The header (blue/grey bar) has a 100% width with a fixed width container inside that is centered.

Answer (score 0):

Defining a `width` of pixels to a `div` usually gives it a fixed layout, while using percentage gives a fluid layout.

For kicks, check out the 960.gs, which uses a fixed layout, and is great for avoiding cross-browser issues:

http://960.gs/

There's also the fluid version of the 960.gs:

http://www.designinfluences.com/fluid960gs/